You want to prevent merges from: 1. `DEV` to `UAT` 2. `UAT` to `Prod` using codecommit
What I did
I created IAM policies to prevent merging the DEV branch into the UAT branch and the UAT branch into the Prod branch in AWS CodeCommit. I used specific conditions to deny actions like Push, MergePullRequest, and CreatePullRequest for these branches.
Why it failed
Despite following the steps and applying the IAM policies, the restriction didn't work as expected. The policies might have incorrect conditions or syntax issues that are preventing them from being enforced correctly. Additionally, CodeCommit’s native permissions or the granularity of control might not be functioning as intended.
Request for help
Could someone assist me with the correct syntax and IAM policy configuration to prevent specific branch merges in CodeCommit?
I need a working solution that blocks merges from DEV to UAT and UAT to Prod.
